# How do you install golang binaries for all users

Tags: go

From all of the Golang tutorials I have read, the way that you install a Go program is by setting the environment variable `GOPATH=~/go` or something similar, and then you can run `go get blah` and Go will download the program and put the binary in `~/go/bin`.  You also have to add `~/go/bin` into your `$PATH` environment variable so that you can run the programs.

How would you go about installing a Golang program into a common location for all users, so that each user on a system did not need to add a PATH environment variable?

The only way I can see of doing it is to make a directory like `/usr/local/go`, and set that as my `GOPATH` when I install the program, and then I need to add `/usr/local/go/bin` into the system-wide $PATH so that all users can run the programs.  Is that how it should be done?

Comment: Just copy the binary to the correct location (like any other install process would do). You can set GOBIN, but if it's a system-wide path, it probably isn't world-writable, and you never want to be building software as `root`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more environment variables that control how `go ...` commands work. See: https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Environment_variables. In this case, you can set `GOBIN` to your desired install location. Ex:

```
GOBIN=/path/to/common/binaries go get blah
```

will put the `blah` binary in `/path/to/common/binaries`. Note that you'll likely have to run with `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way is to use symlinks, so it's obvious where the tool came from e.g.

> $ ls -al /usr/local/bin/brew
>
> lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  admin  28 Nov 17 18:38 /usr/local/bin/brew ->
>   /usr/local/Homebrew/bin/brew

So to make a tool like [godocdown](https://github.com/robertkrimen/godocdown) global to all users:

> `ln -s "$GOPATH/bin/godocdown" /usr/local/bin/`